# Got "you are using unsupported command-line flag: --disable-web-security. Stability and security will suffer" error

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-rc, flags

I got this below error while using Selenium RC for Google Chrome

you are using unsupported command-line flag: --disable-web-security. Stability and security will suffer.
I don't know whats the issue with chrome.

Answer (score 5):

Reference code for flag `--disable-web-security`

> // Don't enforce the same-origin policy. (Used by people testing their
>   sites.)
>
> const char kDisableWebSecurity[]            = "disable-web-security";

It disallows cross scripting code, what are you doing on selenium RC?

Comment: I need to launch chrome browser to do web testing. I'm doing it with selenium RC. 
I can able to do testing in Firefox but its not working in chrome. I don't know much technical details on this. So can you elaborate your answer.

Comment: Did anyone get anywhere with this? (how come I ask this question a lot when it comes to selenium stuff?)

Answer (score 0):

In feb 2013, someone (expert user/dev "PhistucK"; 1498 Posts as of 01/2014) said on the [chrome-discuss gougle-group](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-discuss/O4WpwWvGz4A):

*No, it [the notification] cannot be switched off. You can compile Chromium by yourself and remove the code that shows it.*

Comment: Way to be enterprise friendly.