# google-chrome --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure command line flag not working

Tags: google-chrome

I know this is an existing question, but there is no Clear answer for that.

Google chrome --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure, accessing microphone over http not working. It still show the getuserMedia() cannot be accessed over http.

It shows the below warning banner while opening chrome.

`"you are using a unsupported command line flag --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="http://example.com". Stability and Security will suffer.`

The exact command I run in terminal

`google-chrome --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="http://example.com" --user-data-dir="/home/users/myname/chrome-temp-data"`

`OS Version Ubuntu: 16.04 LTS(64 bit)
Google Chrome Version: Version 63.0.3239.132 (Latest version) (64-bit)`

If this is the right command line flag, why am i getting the "unsupported command line" banner ? Is there is anything I'm doing wrong, any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The banner is just a warning that chrome is less secure in this mode. Some flags do that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215382/got-you-are-using-unsupported-command-line-flag-disable-web-security-stabil

Comment: Are you on example.com or subdomain.example.com?

Comment: @JoshLee not on subdomain. I haven't still figured it out. Btw banner might be a warning, but it says unsupported flag

Comment: Open in New Tab, chrome://flags/ then Reset All to Default.

Answer (score 3):

According to the note in point #3 [here](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins#TOC-Testing-Powerful-Features) that flag was broken in Chrome 63 but fixed again in 64.

Also, you no longer need the `--user-data-dir` flag for it to work.

Comment: Also note that the domain you specify must include the port if you need to specify one in the URL bar.

Comment: On Chrome 67 (OS X): not working, results in a `You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure…` error.

Comment: I'm on Linux Chrome 73.0.3683.103 and it also doesn't work for me. I'm getting a "You are using unsupported command-line flag.." error and the supplied host is still assumed insecure.

Comment: @ÍhorMé drop the quotes. **Bad:** `--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="http://example.com"`. **Working:** `--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://example.com`

Comment: Thanks, will try that next time